# Existence of intersection point By two lines created by four coordinates

Tags: c++

I gather coordinates of four points from user . make a line by the first two points and make another line by rest points. Now the user wants to know if these two lines have a intersection point or not .

Is there any easy way to create this program ???

There is some problem in my program :

1 : If x1 == x2  or  x3 == x4 , RUN TIME erroe appears.

2 : Being match between created lines hasn't been considered.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float x1 , y1 , x2 , y2 , x3 , y3 , x4 , y4;
    cin >> x1 >> y1 >> x2 >> y2 >> x3 >> y3 >> x4 >> y4;

    if ( ( x1 == x2 || x3 == x4 ) )exit(0);



    double slope_1 , slope_2;
    slope_1 = ( y1 - y2 ) / ( x1 - x2 );
    slope_2 = ( y4 - y3 ) / ( x4 - x3 );


    double C_1 , C_2;
    C_1 = y1 - slope_1 * x1;
    C_2 = y3 - slope_2 * x3;




    double intersection = ( C_2 - C_1 ) / ( slope_1 - slope_2 );




    if ( intersection < min ( x1 , x2 )  ||
         intersection > max ( x1 , x2 )  ||
         intersection < min ( x3 , x4 )  ||
         intersection > max ( x3 , x4 ) )cout << '0';
    else cout << '1';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think `exit(0)` would produce the run time error you described.

Comment: _If x1 == x2 or x3 == x4 , RUN TIME erroe appears._ Of course it does. If `x1 == x2`, then `x1 - x2` is _zero_. Then, when you do: `slope_1 = ( y1 - y2 ) / ( x1 - x2 );` you are _dividing_ by `x1 - x2` which, again, is _zero_. So, you've got a divide-by-zero error that raises the `SIGFPE` signal and aborts your program.